# How do I remove artifactory from being my default NPM repository?

Tags: artifactory

I was working on a client contract, and they used Artifactory internally. Now that I'm on a different project, I'd like to remove it. I can't even remember how we set it up now, and I must be Googling for the wrong keywords because I can't find anything on this. I just want to see my packages coming from npm again, but Artifactory won't let me have what I want. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove you ~/.npmrc file and try again.
You may need to reload the default .npmrc file provided with npm (not sure about that).

If you are curious, you can probably look into your ~/.npmrc file and confirm that it contains a line like

```
registry=http://<artifactory_server>/artifactory/api/<npm_repo>
```

This is why any request is sent to the Artifactory server rather than the public npm servers.

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about creating that file during setup. Much appreciated.

Comment: I should also add that I found another offending entry in `~/.yarnrc` as well, which became pretty apparenty when yarn wouldn't work and npm would. Thank you again!